# How to animate translate properties with Velocity.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, velocity.js

I have a simple block that is suppose to move left 200px with translateX. It will move left with position left. I can't seem to move the block with translateX or translateY. CSS values for Transform translate will work. Reason to use translate is the performance compared to position. I commented out the position left with Velocity to give you an idea what I'm trying to achieve.

```js
var button  = document.getElementById('button');
var adiv = document.getElementById('panel');
button.addEventListener('click', function(){
    //Velocity(adiv, { left: '100' }, [ 500, 20 ]);
    Velocity(adiv, {translateX: 200}, [ 500, 20 ]);
})
```

```css
#panel {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    background: #ffffbd;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
   }

button {
    top: 90%;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/velocity-animate@2.0/velocity.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>


    <body>
      <div id="topbar"></div>
       <div id="panel">
       </div>
   <button id="button">start</button>
   </body>
```

Comment: Ran into the same issue, right now. Unfortunately I haven't found a solution yet, if I do will let you know. I can even combine translateX and opacity and the opacity will animate but the translate is being skipped completely. I'm running Velocity without jquery.

Comment: Figured it out, velocity has been updated to 2.0 and some code has been changed. New docs are up on github. https://github.com/julianshapiro/velocity/wiki

Comment: Also noticed that the CDN is corrupt and not working with transforms. Download the minified version from Github and include that into your project. Then it will work.

Comment: @woulter125 outstanding... so I guess if I want to use the CDN link for it to work I got to wait till it gets updated. In the meantime i'll use the min.js version of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Velocity V2 there are no longer any `transform` shortcuts such as translateX - just use the css `transform` property properly and it'll work (there are issues in V1 with trying to do that unfortunately).

`Velocity(adiv, {transform:"translateX(200px)"}, [ 500, 20 ]);`

If there's no forcefeeding it'll animate from a value of 0.

Comment: Indeed it works, it also looks like you need pixels to be used as well. Finally an answer!

Comment: Using the single element syntax with V2 and transforms I get an error message `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'pattern' of undefined` — is there something I'm missing here?  

`$element.velocity({
    transform: "translateX(100%)"
});` . 

Here is a codepen with the example throwing the error: https://codepen.io/poopsplat/pen/wxzWvg

Comment: The first time you use `transform` on an element you should use forcefeeding, the "treat it as from 0 if not already specified" bit doesn't seem to be working right now (this is one of the rare cases where it can actually be used correctly when it's working).

Comment: The `transform` property seems to always generate that exception, trying to read the "pattern" property of the tween "sequence", which (the "sequence") is coming up `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

Velocity seems to be picking up steam with version 3 of VUE coming up.
I highly suggest the Velocity 2.0 docs to be a little more updated with information such as:

> In Velocity V2 there are no longer any transform shortcuts such as
>   translateX - just use the css transform property properly and it'll
>   work (there are issues in V1 with trying to do that unfortunately).
>   Velocity(adiv, {transform:"translateX(200px)"}, [ 500, 20 ]);

Or reach out to the VUE team as they are still using the Velocity 1.x examples.

Comment: I completely cut out the whole Velocity Library. I ran into to many problems with no answers for to long. I hope things get up and going soon!

Comment: check out anime.js

Answer (score -2):

Easy example with jQuery:

```
$('.box').on('click', function() {  
  $(this).velocity({
    transform: ["translateX(100px)", "translateX(0px)"]
  }, {duration: 1000});
});
```